# swipe.js swipe/drag support in bootstrap 3.0 carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, swipe, swipe.js

I recently retrofitted bootstrap 3 carousels to my site and added swipe gesture support using jquery mobile swiperight and swipeleft. Like this:

[How to make Bootstrap carousel slider use mobile left/right swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349984/how-to-make-bootstrap-carousel-slider-use-mobile-left-right-swipe)

This works fine, however, the functionality isn't quite what I needed.

Previously I was using swipe.js which provided more of a drag and swipe mechanic. If you place your finger on the image in the carousel and then drag it left or right the image follows the movement instantly. This feels more natural and responsive than the jquery mobile swipe implementation.

I like using bootstrap carousel and swipe.js seems to be more than just a gesture library, it really provides some carousel functionality, so combining the two doesn't seem like an easy fit.

Is anyone aware of a plugin or an appropriate that brings swipe.js like functionality to bootstrap carousel?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution to this problem recently and settled on this plugin: http://ixisio.github.io/bootstrap-touch-carousel/

It's relatively light weight and is written specifically for bootstrap. The only downside is that it requires hammer.js which adds some extra weight, but this isn't a big deal.

Comment: Thanks. We ended up going a different direction so this was no longer a problem for us.