# Bootstrap carousel not sliding on iphone

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap, sliding

I'm building a responsive webpage with bootstrap plugin. Everything works fine in desktop browsers, even in low resolution and toggle device mode (chrome). But when i open the page on chrome or safari, on my iphone, the carousel just don't slide. It goes to the next slide, but without using the sliding effect.

This is the URL: http://diogoalmeida.pt/2/index.html

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
                <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

        <!-- Google Web Font Embed -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!-- Blueimp Gallery -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueimp-gallery.css">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">


        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Menu -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed navbar-green" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
                    <ul class="nav nav-green navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Carousel -->
        <div class="container-fluid myCarousel">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" alt="Banana">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" alt="Banana">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Gallery -->
        <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
            <div class="slides"></div>
            <h3 class="title"></h3>
            <a class="prev">‹</a>
            <a class="next">›</a>
            <a class="close">×</a>
            <a class="play-pause"></a>
            <ol class="indicator"></ol>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="links">
                <a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Banana">
                    <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" style="width:10%;" alt="Banana">
                </a>
                <a href="images/apple.jpg" title="Apple">
                    <img src="images/thumbnails/apple.jpg" style="width:10%;" alt="Apple">
                </a>
                <a href="images/orange.jpg" title="Orange">
                    <img src="images/thumbnails/orange.jpg" style="width:10%;" alt="Orange">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4(custom-touch).js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Blueimp Gallery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.blueimp-gallery-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
                event = event || window.event;
                var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
                link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
                options = {index: link, event: event},
                links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
                blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
            };
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#myCarousel").swiperight(function() {
                    $(this).carousel('prev');
                });
                $("#myCarousel").swipeleft(function() {
                    $(this).carousel('next');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks this the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349984/how-to-make-bootstrap-carousel-slider-use-mobile-left-right-swipe

Comment: this add nothing to do with my question... I have swipe already, that's not my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, the bootstrap auto compiler (website) wasn't including vendor prefixes.

Solution here -> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14973

Answer (score 0):

similar problem .....my problem was that the images were not sliding to the next on small screens , i added to the head and it worked

```
<script src="../resources/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/assets/js/smoothproducts.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/assets/js/theme.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are right that he needs to include the bootstrap js files but the other ones I think not.