# Swipe Gesture not working in Bootstrap 4 carousel

Tags: mobile, bootstrap-4, carousel, swipe

I recently build a Bootstrap 4.0 web site, using Dreamweaver, which contains several carousels. I’ve added the data-touch=”true” attribute to the code, however the swipe gesture does not work on mobile devices, and I can’t figure out why – I’m thinking either something in the code is preventing the mobile gesture from working, or there’s something missing that I need to add somewhere.

My understanding is that one simply needs to add the data-touch attribute to the code for this to work; no additional javascript is required -- at least, that's what the tutorials I've watched tell me. But, it seems I'm wrong about that.

Here’s one of my pages with a carousel: 
https://neilgunner.com/page_Campaigns_1.html

Can anyone suggest why the swipe gesture is not working, and recommend a fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Bootstrap carousel slider use mobile left/right swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349984/how-to-make-bootstrap-carousel-slider-use-mobile-left-right-swipe)

Comment: Sadly, this solution did not work in my case. I added the script (with the id for my carousel, of course!) at the bottom of my page but it did not do the trick. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: For anyone following this thread, I'm pleased to say the swipe gesture is now working on my carousels. The reason: I updated my site from Bootstrap 4.0 to Bootstrap 4.3. Same code, but now, data-touch="true" works, thanks to the updated Bootstrap framework. FYI for anyone experience the same issue.

Comment: hello, I'm using bootstrap 4.5.3 and the touch is native. however it does not work until you touch one of the two arrows to move to the next/previous image; then it starts working, does anyone else has the same problem? thank you in advance :)

Comment: I have this experience as well. I don't have a solution, but I think what's happening is, one has to "activate" the arrows, ie, touching the arrow indicates to the browser that the arrow is active and swipe gestures should now apply

Comment: I can also confirm the problem. I fixed the swiping at least by calling $(...).carousel('cycle');and immediately calling $(...).carousel('pause'); after that. But unfortunately that does seem to break some links on iOS devices (you have to double tap them). The broken links where on a completely other area on my page. I would also be very happy, if someone finds a fix and posts it here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this discussion, so I post this in case someone else stumbles in here as I did.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.5.2 and solved this by using the following:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="5000" data-touch="true" data-ride="carousel">
```

It didn't work for me without all three of the above data attributes set.

Comment: But with this solution, the carousel won't swipe on the first slide. Only if you click on one of the navigation arrows, swipe gets enabled. I need it on slide 1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create the carousel-object after the DOM is loaded and the touchEvents will work. But you have to set the data-attribute for touch to true:

**For Bootstrap 4.x:**

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-touch="true" data-ride="carousel">
...
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel();
```

**For Bootstrap 5.x:**

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-interval="false" data-bs-touch="true" data-bs-ride="carousel">
...
</div>
```

Script:

```
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#myCarousel')
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel)
```