# Swipe not working on the first slide in Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

Swipe on Carousel does not work on mobile on load (with "data-touch" is set to true) unless we click the next button first.

When i try to swipe on the mobile device to next item of the [Bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#how-it-works) it's not working on the first slide but if i used the arrows to change the slide and i went back to the first slide, the swipe works. I tried to add [`data-ride="carousel"`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#usage) also i tried this JQuery code :

`$('#product-carousel').carousel();"`

but it didn't fix the problem. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Hi Abdo, see if this works.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349984/how-to-make-bootstrap-carousel-slider-use-mobile-left-right-swipe

Comment: Did you managed to resolve this? I am having the same issue. The first slide doesn't let me swipe.

Comment: @RA19 I experimented the same issue with Bootstrap 5.2 and the issue was reported [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/37295).

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this for Bootstrap 4.5 ? Swipe on first slide as well?

Answer (score -3):

Please apply

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-touch="true" data-ride="carousel">
```

or

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-interval="false" data-bs-touch="true" data-bs-ride="carousel">
```

depends on existing slider data